# Center a div on the left side of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

Once someone clicks "Here", I want the div to move to horizontally center of the left side of the screen and a `div` to appear and show up on the right side of the screen while being horizontally centered as well.
Here is my code

[My Code! jsbin](http://jsbin.com/diwutukuhu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: just use some simple css transitions with add class?

Comment: How would I go about finding the center and then moving the div to the left center of the center?

Comment: `.hidestuff` is display none? thanks for hiding from us the button that we should click! Yey!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it's not a solid copy/paste of my code :P

Comment: Also your button is inside the `div` element that animates to the left. now reading your question you want to show somethng on the right... to come from the right edge of the screen? Can you please give us an experimental demo so we can really see what you've got so far? All we can see is currently: http://jsbin.com/paguc/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Please before asking any further questions read: [ask]. And know that your simplified code means that you'll get your answer more easily and we'll spend more time doing our stuff instead of asking sub-questions ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Done and done, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use top and left.

```
#wrapper {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -223px /* half of width*/
}
```

Then animate div using:

```
$('button[name="whattoput"]').click(function () { 
    $('div').animate({
        left: "323px" // target position + left margin
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check this 
please make position of #wrapper to relative

```
.hidestuff {
    //display: none;
}
#wrapper {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width: 445px;
position:relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rut2/cvp6eg0t/6/

Comment: I don't understand how this would make my div appear to the left of the left side of the screen